# Ansible: Build an array of object on every iteration

Tags: arrays, ansible

I have this Ansible task:

```
- name: Build array of Templates
  set_fact:
   template: 
     - name: "{{item.name}}"
       element1: "{{item.element1}}"
       element2: "{{item.element2}}"
 with_items: "{{list_of_objects}}"
```

I don’t know how to add the template object I build in one iteration to an array of templates every time I iterate.

At the end of the task iteration, I want to do something like this (python like):

```
output = output + [template]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The play below

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    list_of_objects:
      - name: A
        element1: A1
        element2: A2
      - name: B
        element1: B1
        element2: B2
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        template: "{{ template|default([]) +
                      [{'name': item.name,
                        'element1': item.element1,
                        'element2': item.element2}] }}"
      loop: "{{ list_of_objects }}"
    - debug:
        var: template
```

gives

```
  template:
  - element1: A1
    element2: A2
    name: A
  - element1: B1
    element2: B2
    name: B
```

---

The tasks below

```
- copy:
    content: |
      {{ template|to_yaml }}
    dest: /tmp/my_template.yaml
- copy:
    content: |
      {{ template|to_nice_json }}
    dest: /tmp/my_template.json
```

give

```
$ cat /tmp/my_template.yaml 
- {element1: A1, element2: A2, name: A}
- {element1: B1, element2: B2, name: B}

$ cat /tmp/my_template.json 
[
    {
        "element1": "A1",
        "element2": "A2",
        "name": "A"
    },
    {
        "element1": "B1",
        "element2": "B2",
        "name": "B"
    }
]
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If I try to save template in a file with copy module I get this error:  'list' object has no attribute 'endswith'